# Need some ideas for MySQL stored procedures, functions and triggers

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a school assignment to design a database and to include:

```
* 2 stored procedures
* 2 functions
* 2 triggers
```

While I know how to implement these, I haven't used them IRL and I have a hard time coming up with use-cases.

Any ideas? :-)

(if it helps, my DB design mimics an online bookstore -- e.g. Amazon)

Comment: Hey, I'm also looking for ideas for a stored procedure too. Have you done a Balloon Shop database by any chance? I'm okay at coding in MySQL but I'm struggling to think of good ideas for this. I keep thinking of simple ones like "sort a balloon by price". I believe it would be off-topic if I posted a question like this so I decided to post this in comments instead. I found this question while I was googling "stored procedure ideas". I don't know if you still go on stack but thank-you in advance if you do give me ideas :) If not thanks anyways, I'll try to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Possible stored procedures:

- given author, retrieve list of books (or ISBNs).
- given ISBN, retrieve title and author.

Possible triggers: maintain separate column with lowercased title/author for faster searching. In other words, index those columns, so as to avoid performance killers like `select blah from book where to_lower(author) = 'dan brown'`. One trigger for insert, another for update.